# HSQL in-memory Database used in JUnit Tests seems to Cache table config

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I have a number of JUnit tests that use HSQL databases.  I have come across an odd problem where I have removed a constraint from a JPA `@JoinTable`, but running the test still generates the constraint.

In 2 entity classes, `User` and `Region` lies the problem

class `Region` (simplified):

```
@Entity(name="region")
public class Region implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;

  .. other stuff
}
```

class `User` (simplified):

```
@Entity(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;

  @Column(name = "username", length = 50, nullable = false)
  protected String username;

  ... others

  /**
   * The regions for this user.
   */
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable
  (
      name="user_region",
      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id") },
      inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id") }
  )
  protected Set<Region> regions;
}
```

Originally, the region_id `@JoinColumn` had **unique=true** on it.  This didn't show up any problems in the development database as that already existed, and JPA doesn't attempt to create constraints on pre-existing databases.  I only noticed my error when trying to add 2 users with the same region in a test:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1338)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at $Proxy58.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sw.generic.data.dao.AbstractEntityJpaDAO.update(AbstractEntityJpaDAO.java:75)
    at com.sw.generic.data.dao.AbstractEntityJpaDAO.update(AbstractEntityJpaDAO.java:1)
    at com.sw.generic.data.dao.AbstractEntityJpaDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dc831f68.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.sw.system4.data.user.dao.UserJpaDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11b55346.update(<generated>)
    at com.sw.system4.rawimport.customer.AllocationImportTest.testAllNew(AllocationImportTest.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1335)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; UK_HQL0M5B9C4CJE0FHT1SB8OLVG table: USER_REGION
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; UK_HQL0M5B9C4CJE0FHT1SB8OLVG table: USER_REGION
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManager2PL.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 60 more
```

So I removed it, but when I ran the test again the constraint is still being added and the same error occurs..

```
Hibernate: alter table user_region add constraint UK_hql0m5b9c4cje0fht1sb8olvg  unique (region_id)
```

Why is this?  I've tried an eclipse -clean, a maven clean, restarting eclipse, restarting the computer, all without success.  It seems to be some sort of caching issue but I don't know how to clear it.  Please help!  Thanks.

Version data:

Java 7

Eclipse Kepler

junit 4.12

hibernate 4.3.8.Final

spring 4.1.4.RELEASE

hsql 2.3.2